# Bind9 on Docker can't resolve on host

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, bind

I have a PC on my local network that will run services that I want to access with URL's instead of IP's.

I have followed many guides and articles on how to use Bind9 (and dnsmasq) but always get stuck. Now I'm using Bind9 and docker-compose. Pinging the DNS container results in the message "request timed out".

The configuration files:

**./docker-compose.yaml**

version: '3'

```yaml
services:
  bind9:
    container_name: dns
    image: ubuntu/bind9:latest
    environment:
      - BIND9_USER=root
      - TZ=Europe/Stockholm
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/bind
      - ./cache:/var/cache/bind
      - ./records:/var/lib/bind
    restart: unless-stopped
```

**./config/named.conf**

```
acl internal {
    10.30.0.0/16;
};

options {
    forwarders {
        1.1.1.1;
        1.0.0.1;
    };
    allow-query { internal; };
};
```

Starting the container with `docker compose up -d`, the container starts and it all looks good. The IP of the Bind9 container is 170.20.0.2. The IP of the host PC is 10.30.20.100.

Pinging the host PC results in the `Request timed out` message. When I try `nslookup example.com 170.20.0.2` I get the same result as well as `Server: Unknown`.

Am I missing something...?

Comment: What do you mean by "pinging the DNS container" exactly? Do you expect `170.20.0.2` IP to be accessible from your local network?

Comment: @AlexD Well, yes, but I haven't come that far yet. I just want to test if the DNS works. nslookup should work like that, right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `170.20.0.2` is an internal IP and isn't accessible from the outside of the docker host. You mapped DNS ports to the host and you need to use the host IP to access the DNS service. Read Docker networking documentation.

Comment: @AlexD I have done a lot of reading but I don't understand. So what you are saying is I can use the DNS server IP from another PC on the network but not on the host? I have tried using that and the host PC IP and with nslookup on another PC on the network but that renders the same result.

Comment: You can also try to use `network_mode: host` and remove the ports